# Removing a node from the middle of a singly-linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I still can't seem to figure out the error that I am getting. Here is my code:

```
int remove(ListNode * &head, int length)
{
    if(head != NULL)
    {
        string str = head->word;
        if(str.size() > length)
        {
            if(head->next->next != NULL)
            {
                head->word = head->next->word;
                ListNode* tempNode = head->next->next;
                delete head->next; //segfault
                head->next = tempNode;
                return 1 + remove(head->next, length);
            }
            else if(head->next != NULL)
            {
                head->word = head->next->word;
                delete head->next;
                head->next = NULL;
                return 1 + remove(head->next, length);
            }
            else
            {
                delete head;
                head = NULL;
                return 1 + remove(head->next, length); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return remove(head->next, length);
        }
     }

     return count;
}
```

The goal is to remove any word whose size is greater than the length given in the parameter. The error happens when I try to delete head->next, even though it clearly exist and I am able to print out the word as well. The error I get is

> *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffde3d4d7c0 *** Aborted (core dumped)

I tried to run Valgrind on it, but could not interpret the output as it did not specify any line numbers. 
Thanks for any help on this simple problem.

Comment: If your valgrind output doesn't give line numbers, make sure you are building with the `-g` option to your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: The first part of this answer was before OP edited the code (see new answer below)

This part:

```
head == NULL;
return remove(head->next, length, count + 1);
              ^^^^
```

is bad.

First, you should not set:

```
head == NULL; 
     ^^
```

That should be:

```
HEAD = NULL;
```

Further, you should not call the function again afterwards:

```
return remove(head->next, length, count + 1);
```

As you are done (you just removed the `head` element, so `head` is NULL). Just `return 0;` (or whatever value you want to return).

> Answer to edited question

A problem with your new code is this construct:

```
        if(head->next->next != NULL)  // Here you know that head isn't NULL
        {                             // but head->next can still be NULL so
            ....                      // don't do head->next->next !
        }
        else if(head->next != NULL)   // This check should also be part
        {                             // of your first if-statement. Like:
            ....                      // if ((head->next != NULL) && (head->next->next != NULL))
        }
        else
        {
            ....
        }
```

In general I don't think the use of recursive function calls is good for this problem. A non-recursive approach is:

```
int remove(ListNode * &head, int length)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        // empty
        return 0;
    }

    ListNode *tmp;
    int removed = 0;

    // Remove elements from start of list
    while(true)
    {
        string str = head->word;
        if(str.size() > length)
        {
            // Remove head element
            tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
            ++removed;
            if (head == NULL)
            {
                return removed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No more head elements to remove
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove elements from middel to end
    tmp = head;
    while(tmp->next)
    {
        string str = tmp->next->word;
        if(str.size() > length)
        {
            // Remove element tmp->next
            ListNode *tmp2 = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
            delete tmp2;
            ++removed;
        }
        else
        {
            // Keep current tmp->next and move to next element
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

    return removed;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I fixed that, but I am still getting the same error. I edited the code I have above with the changes.